# EF5 : Manual table mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How to do manual table mapping in Entity Framework 5 using the Code First approach?

What I mean by table mapping is to associate a table name from the database to an entity class with a different name.

Comment: How are you doing your code first?  Data Annotations or Fluent Mapping?

Comment: Data Annotations but I would be interested in Fluent Mapping answers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple.

```
[Table("Foo")]
public class Bar {
      // properties
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is that in the official documentation?

Comment: Well, the documentation is largely spread around... but various articles mention it.  For instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For fluent api:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTargetTable");
    }
```