# In MVC dotnet, should the model class name must be same as database name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

I was going throught this example in this site, 
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_models.asp
(see "Note" after the code in the page. )

In MVC dotnet, should the model class name must be same as database name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not necessarily,

the example here depicts use of Entity Framework(assumed by the dbContext class). Which by default assumes that the table name is same that of model name but obviously you can override it with [Attribute Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12958273/794226) and [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>() 
    .ToTable("t_Department");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary, If you are talking about EntityFramework then you would map your entity class to DB table. Either in EF designer or using Table attribute in case of Entity Framework code first approach. See [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary, it can be done by adding a Table attribute over the model :

```
[Table("Table name on db")]
public class ModelName
{
....
}
```